# AWS Lambda not working with S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am following the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html)

I am following the Python tutorial however I cannot seem to get it to work, and am getting the following error:

```
{"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  20,
  "handler",
  "s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py",
  91,
  "download_file",
  "extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py",
  658,
  "download_file",
  "object_size = self._object_size(bucket, key, extra_args)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py",
  724,
  "_object_size",
  "Bucket=bucket, Key=key, **extra_args)['ContentLength']"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
  310,
  "_api_call",
  "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
],
[
  "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
  407,
  "_make_api_call",
  "raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)"
]],"errorType": "ClientError", "errorMessage": "An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found"}
```

I am trying to get an image from the bucket called 'stylezz-images' with little success. This is my code, as taken straight from the link provided:

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/'
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        print("key: " + key)
        print("bucket: " + bucket)
        print("download_path: " + download_path)
        print("upload_path: " + upload_path)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}-thumbnails'.format(bucket), key)
```

I am using amazons 'S3 Put' test event straight from lambda. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a Python developer, and it looks like the 404 error should come with additional information, however check to make sure the bucket AND key really do exist and that whatever user/role you're using to run the Python code has the required permissions.

Comment: try putting download_path = '/tmp' instead of download_path = '/'

Comment: I have the same exact issue, the problem is that it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't

Comment: This happens only with certain files if the file name has weird characters. Try renaming the uploaded file to something simple such as "test.jpg" and see if that works. Working on a better solution in the meantime...